# How to control boolean rendering in xslt

Tags: xslt, casting, boolean, xml-rpc

To conform with the `<boolean>` [spec of Xml-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec/) I need to transform my `xs:boolean` from `true|false` to `1|0`.

I solved this using xsl:choose

```
<xsl:template match="Foo">
    <member>
        <name>Baz</name>
        <value>
            <boolean>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=".='true'">1</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </boolean>
        </value>
    </member>
</xsl:template>
```

but was wondering if there is a less brittle way of controlling how boolean values are rendered when transformed with xslt 1.0.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution (an XPath one-liner).  :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use**:

```
number(boolean(.))
```

By the definition of the standard XPath function **[`number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-number)** it produces exactly `{0, 1}` when applied, respectively, on `{true(), false()}`

*Beware!* If you use this construction on *strings*, the result will **be true for both 'false' and 'true'**, because, for string parameters, [boolean() is true if and only if its length is non-zero](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean).

**So, if you want to convert *strings*, not booleans**, then use this expression:

```
number(not(. = 'false'))
```

**Below is an XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="number(not(. = 'false'))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <x>true</x>
 <y>false</y>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <x>1</x>
   <y>0</y>
</t>
```

Comment: Excellent als always - but my prefered version `number(boolean(.))` doesn't seem to work ... it always returns `1`. I'll go for the string comparison which will allow me to use a more generic template in my solution.

Comment: It seems `number(boolean('false'))` will return `1` whereas `number(boolean(false))` will return `0` so the remaining question to ultimate happiness is how to retrieve the non-literal value of a xs:boolean element ;-)

Comment: @Filburt: In case you have really a boolean then use: `number(.)`. The reason there ares still questions hanging around is that you haven't provided a complete XML document and the wanted complete result. When people are guessing these, even 10% success rate is huge.

Comment: I admit that I can have everything if I don't give a fully fleshed out example (including source and desired result) but I did explicitly state my source values type is `xs:boolean` ... and I notice there's a typo in my post: `xsl:boolean` isn't really a type. I did dig around before posting my question and tried `number(.)` which yields `NaN`. Anyway you gave 100% and I don't want to seem ungrateful asking why xslt 1.0 won't allow 150% ;-)

Comment: XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0 is not strongly typed and most values in most cases are of type string (that may be castable to other types). And, unfortunately, `boolean(string(false()))` is `true()` -- not false. Therefore, one will have to use `number(not(. = 'false'))` to convert `{'true', 'false'}` to `{1, 0}`